# How do I wrap text in a pre tag?

Tags: html, css

`pre` tags are super-useful for code blocks in HTML and for debugging output while writing scripts, but how do I make the text word-wrap instead of printing out one long line?

Answer (score 1327, accepted):

The answer, from [this page](https://longren.io/wrapping-text-inside-pre-tags/) in CSS:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: `white-space:pre-line;` (and all browser compatible flavors) seems more adequate in some cases (without tabs for instance) as it takes away the space at the beginning of the line (if there are some)

Comment: @MediaVince, `pre-line` collapses all whitespace (not just at the beginning of the line).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space has a table summarizing the behavior of `white-space` values.

Comment: [`word-wrap: break-word`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/word-wrap.html) does not do what the question is asking for, it causes line wraps to happen even in between words. You can delete that line. On modern browsers, you don't need any of the `-moz` or other prefixes.

Comment: @Flimm Though, `word-wrap: break-word` is the only way I can get Gmail Notifier Pro to break the lines (and it doesn't break words in half). This means the program uses an older IE engine, it seems. See here for a confirmation this is the `white-space` replacement in _**IE 5.5-7**_ (not 5.5+, says Mozilla): https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap.

Comment: There's no need to support all those old browsers anymore, today [`white-space: pre-wrap` alone works fine in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_white-space).

Comment: Works like magic

Answer (score 253):

This works great to wrap text and maintain white-space within the `pre`-tag:

```css
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: This is because it's CSS 3 only - see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/248013/221381) from adambox for more compatibility.

Comment: Consider using an automated tool instead for adding vendor-specific prefixes e.g. [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: @loremmonkey Today all browsers support CSS 3, so there's no need for more compatibility.

Comment: Note that this won't break long words, it will only break between words. If you also want to break long words when necessary, add `word-wrap: break-word;`.

Comment: I found in Tailwind there is a class for it named, whitespace-pre-wrap

Answer (score 92):

I've found that skipping the pre tag and using white-space: pre-wrap on a div is a better solution.

```
 <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">content</div>
```

Comment: In my case I wanted to show pre formatted text which contained tabs to make up some table. I used your solution PLUS I added a monspace font so all columns were aligned: `style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-family:monospace;"`

Comment: While this might be easier, there might be more semantic value in using `<pre>` for code blocks.

Comment: Good one, although not exactly about the <pre> tag. Thank you though.

Comment: I know this I'm late to this game, but why is this solution better than setting it once in the stylesheet? I have multiple divs on one HTML output screen that would need this. Seems like a single fix to the element in the stylesheet fixes all the problems.

Comment: @webfrogs Yes, making a .prewrap class would be best.

Comment: If using style sheets is best, then doesn't that mean richelectron's answer is the correct one?  (Compared to this one?)

Comment: Works perfectly if your pre-formatted text is uneven, some of which are very long sentences that exceed the width of the parent container.

Comment: simple and easy answer

Comment: This worked beautiful for me, thank you!

Answer (score 70):

Most succinctly, this forces content to wrap inside of a `pre` tag without breaking words.

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: keep-all
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on ios safari as of current. Long lines will grow the pre causing it to overflow the container. Adding `word-wrap: break-word;` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 23):

I combined @richelectron and @user1433454 answers. 
It works very well and preserves the text formatting.

```
<pre  style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: keep-all;">

</pre>
```

Answer (score 21):

This is what I needed. It kept words from breaking but allowed for dynamic width in the pre area.

```
word-break: keep-all;
```

Answer (score 20):

I suggest forget the pre and just put it in a textarea.

Your indenting will remain and your code wont get word-wrapped in the middle of a path or something.

Easier to select text range in a text area too if you want to copy to clipboard.

The following is a php excerpt so if your not in php then the way you pack the html special chars will vary.

```
<textarea style="font-family:monospace;" onfocus="copyClipboard(this);"><?=htmlspecialchars($codeBlock);?></textarea>
```

For info on how to copy text to the clipboard in js see: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript) .

However...

I just inspected the stackoverflow code blocks and they wrap in a <code> tag wrapped in <pre> tag with css ...

```
code {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif;
}
pre {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Also the content of the stackoverflow code blocks is syntax highlighted using (I think) http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ .

Its a nice setup but Im just going with textareas for now.

Comment: Wouldn't using text areas for something other than input be semantically incorrect? Seems like a weird solution to me.

Comment: Not as semantically incorrect as adding a bunch of formatting styles to a "pre" tag when "pre" suggests that the contained text is pre-formatted and therefore doesnt require additional formatting and is to rather be taken as-is ;) I suggest dont give "semantics" priority over "functional".

Comment: I don't think `<pre>` has any semantic meaning (unlike `<code>`), it simply means that newlines and multiple spaces should be preserved.

Comment: Its short for "pre-formatted". Youre suggesting that its actually short for pre-formatted-newlines-and-multiple-spaces-only?

Comment: The type of content is meant to be specified by an inner tag, depending on the type of pre-formatted text. I would refer my friends to the w3c pre-tag wiki page: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre

Answer (score 15):

You can either:

```
pre { white-space: normal; }
```

to maintain the monospace font but add word-wrap, or:

```
pre { overflow: auto; }
```

which will allow a fixed size with horizontal scrolling for long lines.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the overflow reminder! Great for mobile displays.

Comment: Definitely the best solution for mobile displays

Answer (score 12):

This is what you need to wrap text inside pre tag:

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not really. None of those vendor-specific tags should be used; all those browsers have been deprecated for ages. I believe that even modern versions of Firefox/Mozilla — just to pick a random example — will not accept the `-moz-pre-wrap` any more (they shouldn't, per specs).

Answer (score 9):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap` and vendor prefixes for automatic line breaking inside `pre`s.

Do not use `word-wrap: break-word` because this just, of course, breaks a word in half which is probably something you do not want.

Answer (score 7):

Try using

```
<pre style="white-space:normal;">.
```

Or better throw CSS.

Comment: this one seems to work in IE 7 but not 6. this is the only suggestion that seemed promising for IE... all other suggestions were good for other browsers...

Comment: nevermind must have been a browser caching thing. restarted IE 6 and all is well. cheers.

Comment: Problem with this solution is it will also dissolve newline characters...  E.g., any separation of text into paragraphs will be lost.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `white-space: pre-wrap;` with `overflow-wrap: anywhere;` if your text contains very long words.

A word will be broken even if there is no white-space available to break the line.

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<pre>
HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<pre>`-Element stands for "pre-formatted-text" and is intended to keep the formatting of the text (or whatever) between its tags. Therefore it is actually not inteded to have automatic word-wrapping or line-breaks within the `<pre>`-Tag

> Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it **preserves both spaces *and line breaks***.

[source: w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp), emphasises made by myself.

Comment: It just states the fact, that it is possible to auto-wrap text within a pre-tag though it's not the pre-tag's intention to auto-wrap.

Comment: This is the only correct response to the author's question. Any other answer or possible "solution" encourages the misuse of the <pre> element. Essentially, if you want to put type inside of a <pre> element and have it wrap, use a <p> tag instead, and style it any way that you like with a CSS class.

Comment: I'm not sure why people find it helpful to give this kind of "I'm cleverer than you" advice. No, a <p> tag is not a suitable replacement: it preserves neither whitespace nor line breaks. A <pre> tag is useful for preserving line breaks, but sometimes it is necessary to add additional wrapping, in the same way as any code editor might both preserve line breaks and add wrapping to long lines.

Comment: Just to clarify the quote by w3schools, well-known for getting small details wrong: _usually Courier_ is the kind of thing that should only be told to users sitting in front of Windows XP, because that was the predominant font used for monospaced text back then (as it came pre-installed). `<pre>`, in fact, is only guaranteed to render in a monospaced font available on the system. If you _want_ to _force_ the _specific_ use of Courier, just add the `font-family` to the CSS styling of `<pre>`. Assuming that you _like_ Courier, of course. Which I don't.

Answer (score 2):

**The Best Cross Browser Way worked for me to get line breaks and shows exact code or text:** (chrome, internet explorer, Firefox)

CSS:

```
xmp{ white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word; }
```

HTML:

```
<xmp> your text or code </xmp>
```

Comment: Worked great for me :-)

Comment: xmp has been deprecated since HTML 3.2, has been completely removed from HTML5, and never worked properly to begin with. It wasn't implemented consistently among the various browsers.

Comment: Using  white-space: pre-wrap; and  word-wrap: break-word; in my css,  keeps the indentation of (json) snippets, pre line removes this. (Chrome)

Comment: *Downvoted* because `xmp` is deprecated and removed in HTML5 (see @PeterToTheThird's answer). `xmp` was also an evil source for some exploits.

Answer (score 1):

The following helped me:

```
pre {
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think is better using `white-space: pre-wrap;` because it respects white spaces

Answer (score 1):

in case your using prism or any code formatting library, then you will need to modify booth pre and code tags as follow:

```
pre {
    overflow-x: auto !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap !important;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap !important;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word !important;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}

code{
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: You've written this in 2021 — you should drop all those vendor-specific tags for ancient browsers that nobody in their right mind should be using these days (not because they're 'fancier', _mostly_ for security reasons; they were vulnerable to several exploits, had bugs that have since been corrected, and so forth. Using `!important` has its caveats, but it's worth mentioning in your answer (since nobody else does!). Additionally, it would be nice if you could explain _why_, in this case, `!important` is... important! :-)

Comment: it works. that's what matters (:

Comment: It was just a suggestion, really. Part of the added value of StackOverflow (and related sites) is that answers aren't just snippets of code to copy & paste — instead, the answers explain _why_ that code works. This allows people to learn something they can apply elsewhere... thus my comment!

Answer (score 1):

`<pre>` does it's work, but for code there is `<code>` tag.

Comment: Exactly!

And for showing text input, you have `<kbd>`; and to show terminal output, you get `<samp>`; and there are a few more... it's all about semantics. Which _are_ important in HTML!