# White-space formatting concerns in HTML

Tags: php, html, whitespace

My selected data contains (can be a long string and 'white-space' in it),

example:

```
$row['desc'] = 'abcd       ABCD   1234 more..  "
```

`<td><?=$row['desc']?></td>`

But When I display it in an HTML table in the browser I don't see the white-space formatted like in the database. I want to preserve formatting from the database.

In FireBug I see exactly the same data formatting as in Database.

[*] To preserve the format like Selected data and I tried

```
  $display_desc = array(" ","&nbsp;",$row['desc'])
```

and my `$row['desc']` is dynamic string

But If I do like will have a problem when the `$row['desc']` long string it does not wrap.

Anyone know what is the problem in this case ?

Thanks

EDIT Example in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>test Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Short data</td>
  <td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;">
  long data      long data     long data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data  long data      long data     long data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data 
  </td>
    <td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;">
  long data      long data     long data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data  long data      long data     long data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data data     long data     long data     long data     long data    long data    long data  long data 
  </td>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap in a `<pre>` tag then apply some css: [How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Demo with your sample html: http://jsfiddle.net/B98jc/

Answer (score 1):

Browsers turn two or more regular spaces into a single space.

Using a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) instead tells the browser to render all of the space characters. If you're having trouble with wrapping, you can control that with CSS. But remember that the browser wants to break the string up on things that can actually break, like regular spaces. You might have to insert a regular space in the midst of those non-breaking spaces (or use some fancy JavaScript) to control the wrapping.

With that said, it seems like you want to build a table structure that mimics what's coming from the database. Putting the entire string from your `$row` record into a single table cell doesn't really solve that problem. Your data looks like it's in a fixed-width format, so you might need to loop through each row of data and take the first *x* characters for the first column, the next *x* characters for the second column, and so forth.

Comment: so I have removed the whitspce to &nbsp; but if there is long string ,will have a problem ,the text not wrap .how can I solve this.Thanks

Comment: @Transformer: Read my edit. The browser needs something in the string to actually break on, it won't break on non-breaking characters. You could maybe trick the browser by replacing the single spaces with something like `<span class="spacer"></span>` and use some CSS (`.spacer { display: inline-block; width: 5px; }`) so each `<span>` is about 1 character wide. The browser would then wrap the content as desired and make it appear to have spaces.

Comment: I did not really understand ,I edited my question with the real html code,and thank for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap the output in `<pre>` tags? That will preserve your existing formatting.

Is there a problem with going that route? Or do you need to replace the spaces?

Comment: if there is long string in your <td>long data</td> the data should be wrap automatically.

Comment: @Transformer, on what condition would you wrap? Wrapping ultimately destroys your formatting, the very thing you don't want.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Jakub I think he wants the same behavior as if you pasted the text into Notepad with wordwrap on.  It preserves the spaces but still wraps.

Comment: @Davy8, ok well that makes sense then, he didn't really specify 'word-wrap' as a requirement initially. Just that he didn't want to loose formatting. Good Answer +1 from me.