# Using pre tag inside td

Tags: html, css

I have a problem using `<pre>` tag inside `<td>`. I have JSF datatable and three columns of it. I need all three columns to contain preformatted text.

If I use `<pre>` tag the text is shown preformatted as I need but the width of the columns gets much bigger than then the text.

I can solve this in css by specifying the `white-space: pre-line;` in `<pre>` tag's style. But it only works with firefox and IE, the chrome ignores this kind of style.

So my question: is there a possible way of solving the width of `<td>` which contains `<pre>` tag inside?

EDITED:

My css class:

```
.dt_row {
    height: 8px;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #000000;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

And my datatable:

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{searchBean.searchResult.concordances}"
                 var="concordance">

        <h:column>
            <pre class="dt_row">
                #{concordance.left}
            </pre>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <pre class="dt_row" style="color: blue;">
                #{concordance.middle}
            </pre>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <pre class="dt_row">
                #{concordance.right}
            </pre>
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

EDITED:

I found the solution. Instead of `<pre>` tag, I have used `<code>` and now all data is displayed perfectly.

Comment: how about applying `width` to `td`?

Comment: Stop, stop. You say `white-space:pre-line` doesn't work with Chrome. But it does! http://jsfiddle.net/53eUR/1/ So something else must be going wrong.

Comment: @Mr Lister but if I remove white-space:pre-line form css the IE and firefox shows the same result as chrome. With a huge width columns in a table.

Comment: Then show some more code. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding css class and datatable.

Comment: @Sarfraz I can not apply width to a td becouse the length of the text being generated in td can be change by user specifying the corresponding property.

Comment: @Paulius Matulionis, you need to post the actual HTML document or its URL. The CSS code you posted does not create the problem you describe, for simple HTML markup (a table with `pre` element inside a cell).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `pre` element occupies by default 100% width, i.e. the entire available width. In table cells, however, this is relative to the cell width, and by default a cell with `pre` is just as wide as needed for the longest line. If this is not the case, you need to identify the code that causes a deviation from the default, and modify it.

For example, if you have set a `width` attribute or property on the `table` element, just remove that setting.

Answer (score 3):

How about having a `div` element that houses the `pre` tag and using a `overflow` attribute in the `div`?

The browser would put a scrollbar, but I believe that's okay with you ;-)

Comment: No, this does not work. I have wrapped <pre> with div, added overflow attribute with css. Firefox shows nothing at all and chrome generates scroll bars within each table row.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis Do you have the URL where I can see this?

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis OTOH if you are fine with wrapping text take a look at this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag>.

Comment: Yes I have just deployed it for you in the remote server: http://tekstynas.vdu.lt/dev. Open this link and in the top right corner it will be link FOR INTERNATIONAL VISITORS click on it and choose english. Then in search term specify for e.g. "home" press search. Next you will see a table. Click on link "home" and you will get a table wich is my problem. Use chrome for this, because firefox and IE is ok.

Comment: Restricting the `<td>` that houses the `<pre>` with a width sort of works.  But then since you have tables within tables, they all don't align to each other.  If you need to, you need to be adding more rows to the same table dynamically.

Answer (score -3):

show a truncated version of the text in the table then when you hover over the cell show show the whole lot bit like tooltip. Obviously this may not work with the your context.