# how to force text content to appear in multiple lines in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Output from controller below is rendered without line breaks in IE9
How to force browser to render text in separate lines as created ?

ASP.NET / Mono MVC2 is used in .NET 3.5

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("Line1");
        sb.AppendLine("Line2");
        return new ContentResult() { Content = sb.ToString() };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you trying to do. Browser ignore simple new line, for `C#` it is `\r\n`. Use `<br />` (html tag for new line) or try `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>
   Line 1
   Line 2
</pre>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CQeTX/

Comment: Thank you. Some lines are long and IE9 shows only start of them. How to force lines to wrap to next line so that they are fully visible in pre which is placed to div browser window ?

Comment: @Andrus Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag

Answer (score 1):

When you use `AppendLine`, `StringBuilder` appends newlines.  If you want to show line breaks in the browser, you have to add `<br/>`:

```
sb.AppendLine("Line1<br/>");
sb.AppendLine("Line2<br/>");
```

or

```
sb.Append("Line1<br/>");
sb.Append("Line2<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is part of the html on the page

```
    sb.AppendLine("Line1<br />");
```

or if it is in the code

```
    sb.AppendLine("Line1\n");
```