# white-space:pre-wrap on mobile device

Tags: css, mobile

I thought `white-space:pre-wrap` was a pretty well-supported CSS rule (it doesn't even feature on caniuse) but when I view the result on my phone I see one big wall of text.

Is there any alternative to this, or maybe a compatibility table I can reference?

Answer (score 2):

> pre-wrap
>
> This value behaves as the pre value, except that it adds extra line
>   breaks to prevent the text breaking out of the element's box. ([Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/css/text/whitespace.html))

From this [mozilla post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility) (click the 'mobile' tab) and the fact that the `white-space` property is tagged there as 'NeedsMobileBrowserCompatibility' (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/NeedsMobileBrowserCompatibility) ), it seems like white-space is not supported on mobile as yet.

### Workaround #1

The `word-wrap` property **is** supported in mobile (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap))

So you could produce <strike>the same</strike> very similar results wrapping the markup in `<pre>` tags and adding

`word-wrap: break-word;` to the class. (see [this css-tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/make-pre-text-wrap/))

Something like this:

### Markup

```
<pre>his is the test        paragraph.
    It has all kinds of odd tabs              and spacing in
the
           HTML source code.
    Should they                 be preserved?</pre>
```

### CSS

```
pre
{
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PbGKY/2/)**

### Workaround #2

Wrap the text in a readonly `textarea` element. The obvious issue with this is that you'll have to know the width/height of your text in advance. (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008351/703717))

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PbGKY/3/)**

Comment: That doesn't produce the "same" result, since it breaks words. `pre-wrap` does not.

Comment: It's not even similar, it's completely different. Would you want to read paragraphs of broken words?

Comment: It's similar in that it doesn't break through the box of the parent element. The general look is the same. I wouldn't call this completely different. Also, how about workaround #2?

Comment: Yeah, but then you can't have any formatting like bold or size or whatever.