# Mustache.js allow only line breaks, escape other HTML

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am creating comments from user input and rendering them using Mustache.js after a user clicks 'submit'.  I realize I can replace user input line breaks (`\n`) with `<br/>` to render as HTML breaks, such as

`myString.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');`

and I realize I can make Mustache not escape HTML by using triple brackets

`{{{myString}}}`

However, I would like to escape all user HTML as Mustache would typically do with double braces `{{ ... }}`, with the exception of allowing line breaks with `<br/>`

What is the best way to do this?  I can replace the line breaks after it has been rendered, but that seems like a very inefficient solution, and I'm thinking there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Option 1** - Use a pre tag:

It's actually best (or efficient) that you wrap text in a `<pre></pre>` tag, which will preserve the white space in the text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

And enable word-wrap

[How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)
 - http://jsfiddle.net/X5ZY7/

**Option 2** - Split your string into lines, and use a mustache each:

```
comment = userComment.split("\n")


{{#comment}}
    {{comment}}<br/>
{{/comment}}
```

**Option 3** - Manually escape your string using your [favorite method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) before injecting the 
 tags:

```
var div = document.createElement("div")
div.textContent = comment
comment = div.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")


{{{comment}}}
```

Comment: I really don't want to preserve all white space, but rather just line breaks.  I setup a quick test as well, and it doesn't seem that I can get <pre> tags to actually word wrap (even when it's explicitly set), so the text goes outside the boundaries and flow the the DOM elements.

Comment: I think option 2 or 3 is more what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the suggestions Matt!

Comment: Option 2 should be 
`
{{#comment}}
    {{.}}<br/>
{{/comment}}
`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to add line breaks to a textarea you need to replace \n with &#13;&#10;

Comment: if I use this `text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '&#13;&#10');`  should I render like `<textarea>{{{ response.data.descriptionParser }}}</textarea>`  ?  but still not change line ...