# Mustache js line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I am passing a text with line break to mustache but while rendering the line breaks are not shown. Please let me know , how to add line breaks in the text.

```
var test ="test1"+"\n"+"test2"+"\n"+"test3".
```

I am passing this to Mustache for rendering and expecting this should get printed like

```
test1
test2
test3
```

But the actual result is `test1test2test3` while rendering this.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try with <br>

Comment: This does not works . The br tag itself getting printed !!

Comment: You must escape the html in the mustache template with this `{{{str}}}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `<br>` but in your mustache template you must use `{{{myString}}}` to escape html

Answer (score 5):

The best approach, in my opinion, is to apply the following CSS to the element you want to show with line breaks:

```
white-space: pre;
```

That way, all the `\n` will actually show as line breaks. There are also other ways of handling this, for example see [Mustache.js allow only line breaks, escape other HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251638/mustache-js-allow-only-line-breaks-escape-other-html).

Answer (score 5):

`white-space: pre-wrap`, NOT `white-space: pre` (won't transfer a long string otherwise)