# Setting maximum width of <PRE> tag in GeSHi of PHP

Tags: php, html, css, syntax-highlighting, geshi

I am using GeSHi for Syntax Highlighting. Is there any way to set width of PRE tag generated by GeSHi?

What I mean is I have a textarea with the width of 500px and therefore as usual text is word-wrapped for long lines. And when I send text from my TextArea to GeSHi, it generates a PRE tag  highlighting my code but then it creates a long line instead wrapping like textarea does. Something like this

In below textarea, long lines are word-wrapped like

```
   ---------------------------------------------
   |  This world is big and we are living here |
   |  for a long long time.                    |
   |                                           |
   ---------------------------------------------
```

A PRE syntax highlighted code generated by GeSHi has output something like this

```
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   |  This world is big and we are living here for a long long time.|
   |                                                                |
   |                                                                |
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to limit this PRE tag width to 500px and word-wrap just like textarea. Is there anything possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used GeSHi but you can probably set some CSS for your PRE tag with this

```
 .wordwrap { 
     width: 500px;
     white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
     white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
     white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
     white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
     word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
  }
```