# Text inside <pre> tag is not wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

`response.text` contains the `html` source of `google.com`.
How come the `html` source is not wrapping inside my `<pre>`?
Current solution creates a huge side scrolling area, I'd like any text that goes beyond the window width to wrap.
I want to avoid use of `innerHTML` in this solution.

```
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.text));
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(pre);
```

`css` for `<pre>` ..

```
pre {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    margin: 5px; 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like below,

```
pre {
    outline: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    margin: 5px; 
    white-space: pre-wrap;       
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    
    word-wrap: break-word;       
}
```