# What's the difference between `word-break: break-all` and `word-wrap: break-word`?

Tags: css, word-wrap, pre, word-break

I don't understand why there are two properties that seem to do the same thing, yet their interrelation does not appear to be defined within the spec.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#word-break-property

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#overflow-wrap-property

For example, if I want text wrapped as per [How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag), and some lines contain strings with no spaces (which seems to make Chrome think they're non-breakable (even if they do have commas and such)), do I want to use `word-break: break-all` or `word-wrap: break-word`, in addition to `white-space: pre-wrap`?

Comment: Your question/answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap;` seems to break lines with no spaces in Chrome on my end. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9gtoz2r/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

word-break: break-all`its break the sentence and text in other line`
word-wrap: break-word` its not break the sentence its break the line and full sentence go to next line without break

```css
p {
 width:100px;
 word-break:break-all;
 padding-left:20px;
}
div {
 width:100px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>India's Saina Nehwal won the Australian Badminton Open Super Series title at the State Sports Centre in Sydney on 29 June, 2014. Saina began the match in aggressive fashion as she raced into a 12-8 lead in the first game against Spain's Carolina Marin in the final.</p>
<div>India's Saina Nehwal won the Australian Badminton Open Super Series title at the State Sports Centre in Sydney on 29 June, 2014. Saina began the match in aggressive fashion as she raced into a 12-8 lead in the first game against Spain's Carolina Marin in the final. </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So, well, I'll accept this answer, since no new ones could be posted, however, I think `word-wrap: break-word` is effectively a noop here in your example, because you don't have something like `white-space: pre-wrap`, me thinks.  The whole thing doesn't seem to be very clearly spec'ed. :-(

Answer (score 5):

You can understand this clearly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/q2afq/light/)

```
<p>
    Oooohhh.AslongaswegoteachotherWegottheworldspinninright inourhands.
</p>
<br />
<p class="break-all">
    Oooohhh. As longaswegoteachother. Wegottheworldspinninright inourhands.
</p>
<br />
<p class="break-word">
    Oooohhh. As longaswegoteachother. Wegottheworldspinninright inourhands.
</p>
```

**css**

```
p{
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}

.break-word{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.break-all{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Hm, why is the whitespace in the source text in your first example different from that of the latter two?  That doesn't add to the clarity of what you're trying to point out through CSS.