# How can i make my paragraph go to the next line after a certain width

Tags: php, html, css

So a string is being entered from a database into a paragraph, when the paragraph has spaces the paragraph breaks perfectly but if the string has a word longer than the line it goes off the page as shown below, how can i make it go the the next line instead of off the page?

[image]

here is my php and html code:

```
<div id = "comment">
        <?php
        echo "<div style = 'border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width:1px;'><p class = 'word'>" . $issue . "</p>";
        echo "<p class = 'word info'>" . $author . ' ' . $date . "</p></div>";
        $sql2 = "select * from Ticket_Message where Ticket_Main_id = '$MainId'";
        $query2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
            $message = $row['message'];
            $auth = $row['auth'];
            $date = $row['date'];
            echo "<div style = 'border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px;'>";
            echo "<p class = 'word'>" . $message . "</p>";
            echo "<p class = 'word info'>" . $auth . ' ' . $date . "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>
        </div>
```

and here is my css attempt to fix it :

```
p{max-width: 250px;}
```

basically what i need am trying to do is use css to prevent all paragraphs from extending off the page when the string is longer than the width of the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688767/whats-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-and-word-wrap-break-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
p { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any php code here.

Use css property `word-wrap`

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

Demo: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap