# It is possible to embed plain text into HTML?

Tags: html, css, web, text

I need to embed a huge text file in plain text which contains a lot of information organized by newlines, tabulations and spaces. This text file does not have any html tags, it's just plain text.

I need to show it embedded into an HTML file, because I don't want to write thousands of tags (`<br>`, etc...) to reorganize the text, because if I just paste the plain text into a `<b>` tag into an HTML file, the text is shown as a only paragraph without newlines, spaces and tabulations. I'm not sure how to do this. I can't find any info about that.

Comment: Use `pre` tag to do that

Comment: This sounds like the wrong way to do this, but @Dummy's correct.  To show preformatted content, you should use the `<pre>` tag

Comment: Hi @Dummy i'm testing it. I have a problem with <pre>, huge lines does not fit into the 100% of the width of the screen, they are taking a lot of width with horizontal scroll. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contents in a `<pre>` tag will make use of new lines, white space, and tabs.

If you need the letters to line up on top of each other like in a command line, you're wanting a "fixed width" font.  You can take a look a the `<tt>` tag, or you'd have to set the font for that block to a fixed-width font (which would be a different question)

Comment: i'm testing it. I have a problem with <pre>, huge lines does not fit into the 100% of the width of the screen, they are taking a lot of width with horizontal scroll. How can this be avoided?

Comment: @NullPointerException `white-space: pre-wrap;` should do that for you if you can support CSS 3.  Otherwise, here are some other ways to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/248013/854246

Comment: i need to support old navigators, no css3. Which way whould work without css3?

Comment: What specifically do you need to support? (and "everything" is not a realistic expectation)

Comment: well, this website is dedicated for people with high ages, so they are commonly using Windows XP and internet explorer 6.... i think best option whould be accepted answer in the link you provided me. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML spec requires a block level (or in the case of `<br>`, an artificially line-breaking) tag to break lines. It specifically ignores line breaks and white space in the source, so if you want your raw text to keep its line breaks, find or write a script that converts the \n character to something that causes line breaks.