# Text inside DIV doesn't wrap always

Tags: html, css

I've created editable DIV [here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/YWryKw?editors=1100). Text is wrapping, just like I wanted. But, what I've noticed is that text is wrapping only if it is plain text. On the image below I've pasted some text with markup - and it doesn't wrap. Can I solve this, so text inside DIV will always wrap?

Code for editable DIV:

```
.editableDiv {
  padding: 5px;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
    -moz-user-modify: read-write;
    user-modify: read-write;     
    word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #FAC28A;  
    color: #003399; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that text in a `pre` tag? because: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using `word-wrap: break-word;` on `.spanDateEventHeader` class. This would make sure it doesn't leave the Div.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously using pre element.

Quick solution is to use white-space property on pre element.

Add this to your css:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: I don't use pre element. Only DIV.