# PHP Prepared Statement-- Printing results

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to display information from an SQL query that should only have one result. I want to display the different columns in different places (with different formatting).

Here is my current code:

```
$query = "SELECT artist_ID, name, description, years_active FROM artist WHERE name LIKE ?;";
if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare($query))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $artist)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->bind_result($artist_ID, $name, $description, $years_active);


while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s", $name);
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s", $description);
}
```

Even though I've included the newline character, it just prints these two results on one line. And I can't figure out how to print them without a while loop. Any insight?

Comment: You need a line break (`<br />`) if you're using HTML to echo the results.

Comment: And if you are using php as cli environment and output to a non html document, then you have to take care to use the correct line break sequence for the terminal. `\n` is Linux style (Unix), it will not work under MS-Windows for example or other operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jay Blanchard stated in the comment section of your question...

You ought to use `<br />` as that tells the browser to read it as a new line. Because `\n` and `\r` simply writes a new line in the file output, and by default, the browser does not read a line break in a file as a new line unless there is a `<br />` tag to tell the browser to read it as a new line.

Therefore:

```
printf("\n");
```

should be changed to:

```
printf("<br />");
```

An alternative, if you want the browser to read the new line character as a new line, you can wrap the content in `<pre></pre>` tags.

See more on pre wrapping:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_pre.asp

[How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)

Comment: Thanks so much! I am new to HTML and PHP so I totally didn't realize that

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand this code.
steps:
Delete while loop
Generate an associative array and save it into a variable ($row)
Write a foreach loop so you can print the name and the description for each registry in your array

```
<?php
if($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    foreach($row as $value){
?>

<!--HTML Code-->
<!--This is between the foreach and it's end (})-->
<!--So anything between here will be interpreted by your browser for each element in $row-->
<tr>
     <td><p><?php echo $row['name']?></p></td>
     <td><p><?php echo $row['description'] ?></p></td>
</tr>  

<?php
    } //end of foreach
}
?>
```

Comment: You could also echo out like this: `echo '<tr/><td><p>' . $row['name'] . '</p></td><td><p>' .$row['description'] . '</p></td></tr>';` to avoid closing and opening the php tags repeatedly.