# How to disable horizontal scrolling in HTML pre tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-frontend

I'm trying to disable horizontal scrolling in HTML pre tag

I'v tried this:

```css
pre {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

but it does not work correctly

it appear like this:

[image]

The text keep going to left edge.
(the direction of my html page is RTL Right to Left)

Any Suggestion?

Comment: try `overflow-x`

Comment: Also, you want to apply `text-align: right;`

Answer (score 13):

`overflow-x: hidden` cuts the text off, but doesn't wrap it.

The `white-space` CSS property instead sets how white space inside an element is handled; `pre-wrap` preserve sequences of white space, lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

This article gives a lot of great info on the pre tag: https://mediatemple.net/blog/tips/considerations-for-styling-the-pre-tag/

Comment: Work! Right answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
text-align: right !important;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
```

Also, this article could be interesting for your work: https://alfy.me/2014/07/26/lets-talk-about-rtl.html

Hope it helped! Good coding! ;)

**Edit:**

I will explain myself.

By adding `text-align: right !important;` we are forcing the text to be aligned right, being your website a RTL, this is the way to go.

By adding `overflow-x: hidden !important;` we are saying that we don't want horizontal scrolling.

The `!important` statement is used to give priority to **this** css rule, it is used to override other styles.

Comment: When you start using `!important` there is no way back :) there is always a way to get around without using it.

Comment: The same problem again
currently the text keep going to the left edge
i want to make the text stop at specific limit, then start a new line.

Comment: @Morpheus Yes, indeed. `!important;`is a Rambo solution, but I figured out that @askm had to override styles

Comment: @askm Then I think that your question wasn't well explained or I understood badly. If you want the text not to 'touch' the edge of the screen. Put your text inside a container (div) and give it a size and a position so you can control it. Also, read the article I linked, it can help you with the style of website you want to make. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is found in this post: [How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/248011/3416774)

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```