# The content doesn't fit inside the <pre>

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm studying a little bit css/html/bootstrap and I was wandering why, in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/og1w9ykq/3/), the text inside the `<pre>` is not wrapped correctly and the horizontal scroll bar is added.
Is there a way to remove it and fit all the content in a better way?

Please take a look also to the following image.
Thanks and regards

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```