# VueJS newline character is not rendered correctly

Tags: javascript, string, vuejs2, newline

I got the following problem, I read data string from an API which contains new line characters `\n` and I want to display them correctly in my template.

But when I do something like:

```
<p>{{ mytext }}</p>
```

The text is display with `\n` characters in it like normal text.

The text string from the response is in the format of `"Hello, \n what's up? \n My name is Joe"`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can try wrapping `mytext` in `<pre>` tags or adding `white-space: pre;` css to your `<p>` tags

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Not even a vue issue you could simply use CSS and apply `white-space: pre;` to the content. You shouldn't need an additional package for this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'Hello Vue.\nThis is a line of text.\nAnother line of text.\n'
  }
})
```

```css
.pre-formatted {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="pre-formatted">{{ text }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that if you need the text wrapped you can use ```white-space: pre-wrap;``` [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap;` did the trick for me! Note that as it seems `white-space: break-spaces;` does a very similar thing. In fact, I couldn't distinguish it.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `<pre></pre>` tag to **pre**serve the **pre**formated text. More info [MDN Pre tag docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'Hello, \n what\'s up? \n My name is Joe'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ text }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't link to w3schools for new users- the site has a history of having outdated material. MDN Docs should be used instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: Unfortunately the `<pre>` tag overrides font styles, so this isn't a CSS-free solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issus i was using `vue-nl2br`

check it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-nl2br)

**Install**

```
npm install --save vue-nl2br
```

**Usage**

```
import Nl2br from 'vue-nl2br'

Vue.component('nl2br', Nl2br)
```

**View**

```
<nl2br tag="p" :text="`myLine1\nmyLine2`" />
```

result :

```
<p>myLine1<br>myLine2</p>
```

Comment: You're saying OP has to download, install, and use a package just to show new lines??

Comment: Yes , but is not just show its converting /n tag to <br>

Comment: seems extremely excessive for that functionality

Comment: Yes I agree :/  !

Comment: Yes it is a little "over powered" for now it works maybe I find a better solution. If so I will post it here.

Comment: i've attached an example on my answer, you no need dependencies

Comment: Saw it, much more easy... 
I know this property put this was nothing I came up with :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I used CSS to resolve it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    yourText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \n consectetur adipiscing elit, \n sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \n \n Ut enim ad minim veniam, \n quis nostrud exercitation ullamco'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<p id="app" style="white-space: break-spaces">{{yourText }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to split string in multiple `<div>` elements.

I use this also with i18n plugin and I like it because I don't need to touch CSS.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: ['Hello Vue.','This is a line of text.','Another line of text.','']
  }
})
```

```css
.pre-formatted {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="text of text">{{ text }}</div>
</div>
```