# Javascript str.split at colon char and add line break

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js

I feel a bit dumb here. I'm trying to add a line break after a colon in a string like this:

`LOCATION: SOME OTHER WORDS AFTER`

I would like it to become

```
LOCATION:
SOME OTHER WORDS AFTER
```

My method, being called from a Vue loop, is this:

```
handleName(name) {
  if (name.includes(":")) {
    return name.replace(":", ":\n");
  } else {
    return name;
  }
}

// the above simply adds a line in the name var but does not actually render an HTML <br>
// I tried using name.split(':'), but for some reason it splits the sting by individual letters.
```

Maybe because it's being called from Vue like `{{ handleName(location.name) }}` I have to handle it differently?

Comment: use `<br />` instead of `\n`?

Comment: So replace it with an HTML `<br>` instead of a `\n`.

Comment: @NickParsons That prints the break as part of the string, i.e. LOCATION <br /> SOME OTHER WORDS.

Comment: It's being rendered like that because whatever framework you're using is escaping/encoding the HTML tag. You'll need to provide more context and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979287/replace-n-to-new-line-on-vuejs

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yeah, it's getting called from a Vue loop `{{ handleName(location.name) }}` so I'm not sure how to return HTML to that.

Comment: Use the `v-html` directive.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen that was it, thank you sir. If you want, put it in an answer and I'll accept it so you get the fame, glory and riches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following demo features a function that will break text after a colon on a given string. This function will render the text in HTML or return the edited text as a string value to used elsewhere.

```
/** 
 * colonBreak(data, DOM = false)
 =------------------------------=
 * Edit text in a particular format pattern:
 *   Insert a line break after any colon.
 =------------------------------------------=
 * @param {string} data - There are two forms of strings that can be accepted:
 *                        1. a literal string or template literal 
 *                        2. the selector of a DOM element that has the text 
 * @param {boolean} DOM - If undefined it defaults to false 
 *                        true:  data represents the selector of a DOM element
 *                               text of DOM element will be formatted
 *                        false: data is the string to be formatted
 =----------------------------------------------------------------------------=
 * @return {string}       if DOM is false, a formatted string will be returned. 
 *            or 
 *         {undefined}    if DOM is true, undefined will be returned and the DOM 
 *                        element text content will be formatted
 */
```

---

#### Explanation

When dealing with the text of DOM elements, HTML formats text by default so that multiple whitespaces and line-breaks are normalized. [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property is used so that the whitespaces and line-breaks are preserved (`\n` is not ignored). `.innerText` or `.textContent` can be used to extract the text but it's important to apply `.innerText` to render the formatted string back into the DOM element.

```
string = node.innerText;
```

The heart of this function consists of [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method witch splits the string by a RegExp delimiter into an array of strings:

```
string.split(/([\w]+:)\s*/)...
```

The RegExp delimiter instructions are as follows:

1. `(`...`)` capture the match within the parenthesis and use it as a replacement
2. `[`...`]` match the literal and/or class of each character and/or meta-character
3. `\w`      meta-character that matches any alphanumeric character (including underscores)
4. `+`       quantifier indicating match of ***one* or more** consecutive instances of the match preceding it
5. `:`       literal colon
6. `\s`      meta-character that matches a whitespace
7. `*`       quantifier as `+` but matches ***zero* or more**

Last method used is [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) which will join all the strings of an array into one complete string by a given delimiter:

```
let formatted = string.split(/([\w]+:)\s*/).join('\n')
```

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
/* 
There are two examples of input:
  1. A <p> with text (located in HTML window of demo)
  2. A string assigned to the variable dataString (below)
    (NOTE: colonBreak() normalizes spacing as well)
*/
const dataString = `keyX: xXxXxXXxXxXx keyY:yYyYyY YyYyYy keyZ: zZ zZ zZ Zz Zz Zz`;

/* 
See documentation in post about the parameters and return
*/
function colonBreak(data, DOM = false) {
  let node, string;

  // if DOM parameter is true...
  if (DOM) {
    /*
    - Reference the DOM element designated by param data
    - Get the textNode within the DOM element
      (NOTE: .innerText preserves whitespaces)
    - Overwrite textNode with the formatted text
      (NOTE: See post on how text is formatted)
    */
    node = document.querySelector(data);
    string = node.textContent;
    node.innerText = string.split(/([\w]+:)\s*/).join(`\n`);
  } else {
    /*
    ...otherwise just return the formatted text
    (NOTE: See post on how text is formatted)
    */
    return data.split(/([\w]+:)\s*/).join(`\n`);
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(colonBreak(dataString));
colonBreak('p', true);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<p>keyX: xXxXxXXxXxXx keyY:yYyYyY YyYyYy keyZ: zZ zZ zZ Zz Zz Zz</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `<br/>` tag instead of `\n`:

```js
handleName(name) {
  if (name.includes(":")) {
    return name.replace(":", ":<br/>");
  } else {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Example in Vue.JS, using the `v-html` directive to display String as markup:

```
<template>
    <span v-html="message"></span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
    return {
      message: "LOCATION: SOME OTHER WORDS AFTER".replace(":",":<br/>")
    }    
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Make sure that you insert an HTML linebreak (`<br>`) instead of a newline character (`\n`). Except inside specific tags like `<pre>`, HTML collapses white-space by default, and the newline will not be rendered as a new line.
2. Make sure that you pass the result of the replace operation to the renderer as HTML, and not as text. If passed as text, the renderer will replace the less than (`<`) and greater than (`>`) symbols in the `<br>` tags with their equivalent entities (`&lt;` and `&gt;`).

In VueJS, you can use the [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive for this:

```
<span v-html="name.replace(/:\s*/g, '<br>')"></span>
```

---

<sup>**(!) Be careful when outputting user-defined content as raw HTML. You might be opening yourself up to XSS (and related) vulnerabilities.**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Normal line breakes like `\n` are rendered as a white space in an html. To actually render a line break, you can use a `<br>` element. Also you don't need to check if the colon exists in the string. You can safely attempt to replace it even if it doesn't exist.

```
handleName(name) {
    return name.replace(":", ":<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any confusion. It is fine to use a `\n` in a string, `span` or whatever.

BUT this works if you assign it to `innerText`. If you or whatever you are using uses `innerHTML` it won't work as expected (see example).

```js
function handleName(string) {
  return string.replace(":", ":\n");
}

let div = document.getElementById('div');
let div2 = document.getElementById('div2')
let name = handleName(div.innerText);
div.innerText = name;
div2.innerHTML = name;
```

```css
div{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='div'>LOCATION: SOME OTHER WORDS AFTER</div>
<div id='div2'></div>
```