# modal-body text flows out - word wrap not working

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

[image]I have created the `modal` pop-up screen and am display some text from database. In that some of the text are very long and it is going out of the `modal` screen window.

am using `<pre ng-bind-html="history.comment" class="wrap-word">` tag but, still it over flow.

Please find my html code below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <h2>Modal Example</h2>
   <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="form-group row">
  <div>
    <table class="table">
   <tr >
     <td >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
     <label>Action:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="action" class="col-lg-10">Approved</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
     <label>User:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="Name" class="col-lg-10">Karthikeyan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
     <label>Comment</label>
      </div>
      <div id="comment" class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="Name" class="col-lg-10">Karthikeyanaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      </div>
    </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
   </div>
   
 </div>
```

Please find the attached screenshot also.

Please find the update screen shot with more information about `<pre>` tag.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I wrap text in a pre tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)

Comment: You can add `white-space: pre;`

Comment: @NishargShah - i have added `white-space: pre;` tag. but still its overflowing. I have attached the recent screenshot.

Comment: can you share your full code ? IN HTML or in angular you can make stackblitz

Comment: @NishargShah - Am unsure about stackblitz...` <div id="historyComment_{{$index}}" style="word-wrap:break-word; width=400%" class="col-lg-10">{{history.comment}}</div>`.. This was my recent change.. but still its not working as expected

Comment: @Karthikeyan stackblitz is online vs code editor when you can save project and share with other person

Comment: edit your question and update your code, if your project is big and you cant share your code, send particular part of your code

Comment: @NishargShah - I have pointing the exact line., where am getting the text overflow issue.

Comment: but from here how i know where problem are located ?

Comment: I added my answer look out it and if its not working tell me

Answer (score 0):

Your grid layout doesn't recognized because you use **table** try to add this code at the top your table tag.

```
<div class='table table-responsive'>
     <table class="table">
     </table>
</div>
```

or try to add this css to your comment section

```
style="word-wrap: break-word;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing, there is the most common issue of overflowing, give the static class to your text to perform task on it

```
.modal-body #historyComment_0 {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: this is not working., please find my complete html file with static data

Comment: how can I find it, you cant give us file of it ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/194597/chat-room-of-nisharg-shah-and-karthikeyan?tab=general join this

Answer (score 0):

Use code below will resolve this issue

```
style={{ whiteSpace: 'unset' }}
```