# Wrapping <pre> to a fixed width such that each line is the same length in characters

Tags: html, css, whitespace, word-wrap, pre

I'm attempting to wrap this long `<pre>` so that it forms a rectangle (rather than having the "jagged" endings I'm getting). I've set `white-space` to `pre-wrap` and `word-break` to `break-all` like [other StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag) have suggested, but it seems like the browser is still applying some heuristics on where to break the line.

I cannot break the `<pre>` into rows a-priori because both the length of the content, as well as the width of the `<pre>` may be dynamic.

```css
pre {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<pre>ER..............................3......|..f1.f1.fSfQ.W....R..|.........K...R.A..U1.0....r...U.u....t.f.....B....1.ZQ....[...@P..?Q..SRP..|...f....D.....f@.....f.&gt;@|..xpu....{.D|.....isolinux.bin missing or corrupt...f`f1.f...{f...{fRfP.Sj.j...f.6.{.........6.{....A......{...d.fa....Operating system load error...^....&gt;b.....&lt;.u........................</pre>
```

What I have:

[image: preformatted text with unequal line lengths]

What I want to achieve:

[image: preformatted text with equal line lengths]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line-break: anywhere;` works well in Chrome (Canary) and Firefox, but not Edge. If the content contains spaces, you should probably use `white-space:break-spaces` rather than pre-wrap as well.

```css
pre {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  line-break: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<pre>ER..............................3......|..f1.f1.fSfQ.W....R..|.........K...R.A..U1.0....r...U.u....t.f.....B....1.ZQ....[...@P..?Q..SRP..|...f....D.....f@.....f.&gt;@|..xpu....{.D|.....isolinux.bin missing or corrupt...f`f1.f...{f...{fRfP.Sj.j...f.6.{.........6.{....A......{...d.fa....Operating system load error...^....&gt;b.....&lt;.u........................</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great on Firefox. But on Chromium 79.0.3945.79, it still looks broken: https://i.imgur.com/ZvmGCj8.png It looks like `line-break: anywhere` will be added in Chrome 80 later this week. Is there no cross platform way to do this?